# How to grep only duplicate key:value pair in python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have following python dictionary.

```
a={'name':'test','age':'26','place':'world','name':'test1'}
```

How to grep only duplicate key:value pair from the above?

Output should be:

```
"name: test and name:test1"
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters but because they *do* have a `set`, and the two strings aren't identical, they actually can find *"duplicate keys"*!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: good point! The values are not unique now..

Comment: I have missed the single quotes. Now its dict. can we get duplicates now?

Comment: @rcubefather, just print a, then you'll realize the reasons for downvotes mate

Comment: @nafas. Thanks. I have edited my questions. now its not set.

Comment: @rcubefather each key may have only one value

Comment: where is the duplicate key: value pair !? omg, i can't see anything! ;) printing **a** in python console show this `{'age': '26', 'place': 'world', 'name': 'test1'}`; because the key **'name'** is updated with value **'test1'** and that's how dicts works

Comment: @Tanmaya Meher. Yes duplicates been removed only when we execute that program right? My question is how to identify if somebody added a duplicate key with different value?

Comment: @rcubefather are you talking about an issue in a dictionary literal in the code? I.e. you want to search the *text* of your program for dictionary literals with the same key more than once?

Comment: @rcubefather you can analyse the python source code manually; but if you want to automatize it, then you can write another python code which will read your first python source code file (where duplicates are there ) and remove it. But there is no need to do that until you have lots of such duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

python dictionaries's key can't repeat, so 'name':test, 'name':test1 can just keep one. the other will be override.

Comment: Thanks. But somebody written a program with duplicate key but different values by mistake. I want to grep that key:value pair. is there any option?

Comment: @rcubefather no, it's impossible; *listen to what you're being told*. Only the *last* value inserted for that key is still available; all of the others are gone.

Comment: @rcubefather: you'd have to analyse the source code, you cannot do it from Python after the literal syntax has been run.