# How to check if there are equal values associated to a key in Dictionary ,Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, key, key-value

I explain better my problem:

I have a dictionary made by:

```
d={'name':(values), (values), values), 'name2':(values),(values), ...ecc}
```

so values are tuples.
I want to check if some tuples associated to a value are the same.

Comment: Dictionary already maintains a check for **unique keys**

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536457/how-to-grep-only-duplicate-keyvalue-pair-in-python-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment51032953_31536457) may help.

Comment: yes, I change my question, my problem is different to be honest

Comment: Well. Do you know "print" function? So try printing your dictionary!!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> d={'a':3 , 'b':5, 'c':1, 'a':3, 'b':5}
>>> d
{'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 5}
>>>
```

Dictionaries can not have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid Python dictionary, you can't have duplicate keys to begin with...